# How can we draw a vertical line in the webpage?

Tags: html, css

For horizontal it is `<hr>`. but for vertical line?

Answer (score 33):

You can use `<hr>` for a vertical line as well. 
Set the `width` to `1` and the size(height) as long as you want. 
I used 500 in my **example(demo):**

With `<hr width="1" size="500">`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LxSYY/)**

Comment: Simple and most effective solution for <VR> +1 from me

Comment: `<hr style="width: 1px; height: 100px; background: black; border: none;" />` worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

There are no vertical lines in html that you can use but you can fake one by absolutely positioning a div outside of your container with a `top:0;` and `bottom:0;` style.

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.vr {
    width:10px;
    background-color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:150px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/andresilich/RJ5ax/)

Answer (score 1):

That's no struts related problem but rather plain HMTL/CSS.

I'm not HTML or CSS expert, but I guess you could use a div with a border on the left or right side only.

Answer (score 1):

`<hr>` is not from struts. It is just an HTML tag.

So, take a look here: http://www.microbion.co.uk/web/vertline.htm 
This link will give you a couple of tips.